# Python attempting to file.write an entire file

Tags: python

I am attempting to use the `file.write` function to create new objects, and when I do that I need to keep the already existing objects in the library `Trackobj`

```
import TrackObj
TRACKNUM = -1

if TRACKNUM < 11:
    TRACKNUM += 1
    file = open("TrackObj.py", "w")
    file.write(str(TrackObj))
    file.write(("track" + str(TRACKNUM)))
    file.write("\n")
```

I am trying to do this by writing the file then writing the new variable but when I do it just prints out the location of the file. How could I get around this?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call `str` on a module, is that right?

Comment: That code doesn't print anything. What do you mean?

Comment: You're trying to import *and* open as a file the same Python module. That's highly suspect. What is the goal here?

Comment: @Stuart Sorry, I meant it writes out the file location but I wanted it to write out the contents of the file.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo TrackObj is a library I made in order to create new onjects in my game, the code seen here is a file to test writing into the this file (I will turn the file into a function once it works). What makes importing and opening in the same file suspicious though?

Comment: `import` is used to call functions from a Python module. It, among other things, parses the file into the Python AST, then (often) compiles that into some sort of bytecode, and *then* executes the code. By the time the `import` line is done, the original *text* of the file is long gone.